# Сделать агрегацию данных

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте! Пишу проект на ASP.NET MVC5.

Есть коллекция объектов, к примеру:

```
public class ProductState
{
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public int State { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

И я хочу вывести таблицу типа:

```
      | Name     | Name     | Name 
---------------------------------------
State | Quantity | Quantity | Quantity  
---------------------------------------
State | Quantity | Quantity | Quantity    
---------------------------------------   
State | Quantity | Quantity | Quantity    
---------------------------------------
```

Буду очень рад, если кто-нибудь подскажет, как это сделать.

Comment: Я так понял все значения уникальны?

Comment: К примеру есть продукт №1 и продукт №2. Они могут быть в разных состояниях. К примеру собран, покрашен и т.д. И в таблице должно отображаться, какое количество продукта, находится в каждом состоянии.

Comment: Ну или к примеру, по горизонтали названия продуктов, по вертикали номера складов, а в пересечении количество продукта на каждом складе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение в лоб:

[image: Пример работы приложения]

```
class Program
{

    public class ProductState
    {
        public int Name { get; set; }
        public int State { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dataList = GetDataList();

        //Получаем все имена и статусы
        var names = dataList.Select(x => x.Name).Distinct().ToList();
        var states = dataList.Select(x => x.State).Distinct().ToList();

        //Далее генерирую HTML таблицу
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.AppendLine("<table bordercolor=\"black\" border=\"1\">");

        //Так как таблица формируется построчно, то первым делом выведем все имена (Причем первую добавляем пустой)
        stringBuilder.AppendLine("<tr>");
        AddCell(stringBuilder, string.Empty);
        foreach (var name in names)
        {
            AddCell(stringBuilder, name.ToString());
        }
        stringBuilder.AppendLine("</tr>");

        //После чего формируем каждую строку со значениями
        foreach (var state in states)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendLine("<tr>");
            AddCell(stringBuilder, state.ToString());
            foreach (var name in names)
            {
                var item = dataList.First(x => x.State == state && x.Name == name);
                AddCell(stringBuilder, item.Quantity.ToString());
            }
            stringBuilder.AppendLine("</tr>");
        }

        stringBuilder.AppendLine("</table>");

        //Сохраняем и открываем документ
        File.WriteAllText("index.html", stringBuilder.ToString());
        Process.Start("index.html");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Добавление ячейки
    /// </summary>
    private static void AddCell(StringBuilder stringBuilder, string data)
    {
        stringBuilder.AppendLine($"<td width=\"100px\">{data}</td>");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Получение списка с данными
    /// </summary>
    private static List<ProductState> GetDataList()
    {
        return new List<ProductState>()
        {
            new ProductState(){Name = 1, State = 10, Quantity = 1},
            new ProductState(){Name = 1, State = 20, Quantity = 2},
            new ProductState(){Name = 1, State = 30, Quantity = 3},
            new ProductState(){Name = 2, State = 10, Quantity = 4},
            new ProductState(){Name = 2, State = 20, Quantity = 5},
            new ProductState(){Name = 2, State = 30, Quantity = 6},
            new ProductState(){Name = 3, State = 10, Quantity = 7},
            new ProductState(){Name = 3, State = 20, Quantity = 8},
            new ProductState(){Name = 3, State = 30, Quantity = 9},
        };
    }
}
```

P.S. Стринг билдер можно убрать, тут главное понять что таблица формируется построчно. Потому мы сначала достаем все уникальные значения имен и статусов.
После чего проходим по всем статусом (Так как они являются строками). После чего проходим по всем уникальным именам и ищем соответствующее значение в общих данных, после чего соответственно их выводим.